# Why can't we access function via obj.prototype.function(), why prototype function can't access 'this'?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, prototype-chain

How 3 different calls are different from each other?

```js
let Person=function(name){
    this.name=name;
};

Person.prototype.func=function(){
    console.log('Hey I am '+this.name);
};

let jay=new Person("jay");

jay.func(); /*This Works*/
jay.__proto__.func(); /*This doesn't have access to this.name? why?*/
jay.prototype.func(); /*This gives error, Why?*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
jay.__proto__.func();
```

you invoke the `func` function with a calling context of everything that came before the final dot: that is, with a `this` of `jay.__proto__`, which is the same object as `Person.prototype`:

```js
let Person=function(name){
    this.name=name;
};
Person.prototype.func=function(){
    console.log(this === Person.prototype);
    console.log(this === jay.__proto__);
};
let jay=new Person("jay");
jay.__proto__.func();
```

The `name` property is on the `jay` instance itself. It's not on the prototype, so referencing `this.name` inside the method when `this` is the prototype doesn't show the `name` property of the instance.

You could also make the call work with the proper `this` if you use `.call` instead: `jay.__proto__.func.call(jay);`, which will call the function with the `this` set to `jay` not `jay.__proto__`.

> `jay.prototype.func();` /*This gives error, Why?*/

The `.prototype` property is a bit confusing. It only usually has meaning when it's a property of a *function*, in which case, created instances from that function have an *internal prototype* (or `__proto__`) of that prototype object.

On normal instances and pretty much everywhere else, the `.prototype` property doesn't mean anything special and likely won't exist. So there's nothing that exists at `jay.prototype`.

Comment: thanks, i understood .prototype is used with class or function constructors, whereas .__proto__ is used with instances.